How to recreate this blurry shadow and light effect in illustrator, bonus points if I can make the light and shadow react to the shape

I can't seem to be able to recreate this effect within Illustrator (effect in image), my shadows tend to be too harsh and doesn't rotate with shape.

I believe you can get close enough in illustrator, what method have you tried? could you [edit] your question to add more details?

I would use Photoshop or a similar raster image editor for this TBH.  Blurs and shadows are much easier to make in raster software.

As you hopefully see, there's not only a shadow, there's also a light reflection in the right side. It's visible, because the background has a white to grey gradient:

The image above my rough version of the thing.
If you group all items together they surely rotate and move as one. But if you expected that the light would stay the same and the shadow and the reflection should evolve as the mid part is moved or rotated you should build this all in 3D. I skip it and show only a 2D construction.
In the next image the background gradient is removed. The pieces are moved apart. The white part has got a dark background to stay visible.

A is the shadow. B is the actual shape. C is the reflection. A and C both contain separate pieces. B is a rectangle with gradient fill and it presents something which is highest at the middle.
In the next image A is shown fully disassembled. C has a thin solid line at the edge of the rectangle plus the corresponding parts for A1 and A2, but white and flipped.

A1 is a blurred rectangle which is clipped to make the right edge solid. A1X shows the whole rectangle and the clipping mask. A2 is a triangle which is filled with a gradient. The gradient is right to left from opaque grey to fully transparent same grey. It makes the shadow solid at the top and bottom corners. The opacity is reduced for subtler effect.
The white parts contain, as alredy said a bright white line and the rest are the same as A1 and A2, but instead of grey, the color is white and the shapes are flipped horizontally. The white line maybe is too thin to be noticeable.
I must admit that this is very rough. Photoshop has better blurs for making all in a simpler way. Lens blur would be perfect to get the shadow and reflection both as single pieces.

Thank you so much! You explained it so well, truly thank you!
